# A decimal die is tossed 4 times, thus producing a series of 4 random digits...?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A decimal die is tossed 4  times, thus producing a series of 4 random digits.
The series is said to be increasing if from the second digit onward, each digit stands for a larger number than the previous digit.
For example: $1569,\space 1234,$ and $2579$ are increasing.

The question is: what is the probability of obtaining an increasing series?

Comment: **Hint.** There are $\binom{10}{4}$ strictly increasing sequences of four digits. Why?

Answer (score 3):

Every increasing sequence of four digits corresponds to a four-element subset of $\{0,1,2,\dots,9\}$. This means that the number of successful results is $$\binom{10}{4}$$

The total number of possibilities is just $10^4$, so our final probability is

$$\frac{\binom{10}{4}}{10000}=\frac{\frac{10\cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7}{4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2}}{10000}=\frac{21}{1000}=0.021$$

Answer (score 0):

In how many ways you can make an increasing sequence?

There are 10 digits to choose from. You can choose any four in $10\choose4$ ways. Now you  have only one order to arrange them i.e. in increasing order.

So our answer to this question is $10\choose4$.

---

And, the total number of combinations are $10\cdot10\cdot10\cdot10=10^4$

---

Rest is obvious...  $\dfrac{required}{total}=\dfrac{\binom{10}{4}}{10000}=0.021$